# Proving stokes theorem on chains (spivak)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

[image]

I am having troubles with the formula after "note that":

I don't see how the formula is $0$ if $j \not= i$. If I calculate $(I^k_{(j,\alpha)})^{\star} (fdx^1\wedge ... \wedge \hat{dx^i} \wedge ... \wedge dx^k)$   I will get $$f(I^k_{(j,\alpha)}(x^1,...,x^{k-1}))(dx^1\wedge ... \wedge \hat{dx^i} \wedge ... \wedge dx^k)((I^k_{(j,\alpha)}(x^1,...,x^{k-1}))(DI^k_{(j,\alpha)}(...))$$ but the matrix representing $DI^k_{(j,\alpha)}$ will have diagonal 1's everywhere except the jth row will be a 0 row. I can't see how this could possibly lead to the result stated

any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the cube $I_{(j, \alpha)}^{k}$, the $1$-form $dx^{j}$ vanishes because $x^{j} \equiv \alpha$ is constant. If $i  \neq j$, the wedge product with $dx^{i}$ omitted contains $dx^{j}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more please - As you said, on the cube $I^k_{(j,\alpha)}$ the 1-form $dx^j$ vanishes, then wouldn't we get everything $= 0$ as the wedge with $0$ is $0$?

Comment: When $i = j$, you omit $dx^{i} = dx^{j}$, and the remaining evaluations are non-zero. :) In case an example helps, think of the boundary of a square: On the vertical sides $I_{(1, \alpha})^{1}$, you have $dx^{1} = 0$. The integral of $dx^{1} = dx^{1} \wedge \widehat{dx^{2}}$ over a vertical side vanishes ($2 = i \neq j = 1$), but the integral of $dx^{2} = \widehat{dx^{1}} \wedge dx^{2}$ doesn't ($i = j = 1$). Analogously, on the horizontal sides $I_{(2, \alpha)}^{1}$, you have $dx^{2} = 0$, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot :)!

Comment: As @lampj20la says, the matrix representing $DI_{(j,α)}^k$ will have diagonal 1's everywhere except the jth row will be a 0 row. Following Theorem 4-9 of Spivak, when $j = i$, we should also have a factor of $det DI^k_{(j, \alpha)}$, but won't this always be 0?

Comment: @KrishnanMody The matrix $DI^k_{(j,\alpha)}$ is a $k$ by $k-1$ matrix, so that theorem does not apply.

Comment: Why did the regions of integration changed?